# How to find all shortest paths between two nodes in a weighted undirected graph?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

How to find all shortest paths between node 1 and N in a weighted undirected graph? There can be multiple edges between two nodes.

I want to find all nodes that can be on a shortest path. For example:

> 10 11
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 1 3 1
>
> 3 4 2
>
> 4 5 1
>
> 5 6 1
>
> 5 10 2
>
> 1 7 1
>
> 7 8 3
>
> 7 9 2
>
> 9 10 2
>
> 8 10 1

The answer is

> 1
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10

because there are two shortest ways

> 1 7 8 10

and

> 1 7 9 10

Comment: What do all those lists of numbers mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm to find all the shortest paths between two nodes?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38000/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes)

Comment: First two numbers are how many vertices and edges are in a graph. Other numbers are descriptions of edges A, B, C, means A - B weigh C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell whether a vertex $v$ is along some possible shortest path from $s$ to $t$, compute $d(s,v)$ (the length of the shortest path from $s$ to $v$) and $d(v,t)$, and then.....

You can compute $d(s,v)$ for all vertices $v$ efficiently using....

(It's your exercise, so I'll let you have the pleasure of working out how to fill in the blanks.)